# Network Solution to allow LAN to communicate to a different SubNet via a Ubuntu BOX

Tags: networking, iptables, bridge, route, nc

[image]

EDIT: I have added a topology diagram to make it clearer.

I want to access the subnet 172.19.X.X (BLUE) from LAN->M2

I am already able to do via M1 which has a static route.

I trying to solve a specific situation and dont know how to think about it. I have a LAN which wants to listen to UDP packets and establish TCP connections on a different subnet 172.19.X.X where a static IP 10.2.4.81 acts as a gateway. The gateway and LAN are on different network interfaces.

I am able to listen to this

I have a Ubuntu 20.04LTS server which has 2 network interfaces

ETH0 -> Static IP -> 10.2.4.82 / Gateway 10.2.4.81

ETH1 -> Gets DHCP from a Router and is on a LAN -> 10.13.100.X

10.2.4.81 acts as a gateway for another network 172.19.X.X

I have added a static route
route add -net 172.19.0.0 netmask 255.255.0.0 gw 10.2.4.81

This allows me to access software bound to 10.13.100 subnet access 172.19.X.X subnet

I have other computers on LAN which also need to reach 172.19.X.X but has only 1 network interface

I am basically looking for a way where any traffic destined for 172.19 from LAN is routed to ETH1 interface and any response is routed back to the machine.

Question:

1. Is this a IP forwarding problem that I need to think about ?
2. Is there a bridging solution where somehow I bridge ETH0 and ETH1 and they appear to be on the same network and hence local lan machines can also add a similar static route to access the 172.19.0.0 subnet ?
3. What is the most optimal way to solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

If your M1 is the default GW for M2 and M3 and [ip forward](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-turn-on-off-ip-forwarding-in-linux) is enabled, you dont need to do anything... but you can add static route on them, something like route add -net 172.19.0.0 netmask 255.255.255 gw 10.13.100.143 (ip of ubuntu box)

Comment: Can you please elaborate a bit more ?

Comment: So IP 10.13.100.M1 will be a static route for 10.13.100.M2 on the LAN. Can I do route add -net 172.19.0.0 netmask 255.255.0.0 gw 10.13.100.M1  on machine with IP 10.13.100.M2 and this will ensure M2 can see all networks M1 sees ?